# Kivy : childeren GridLayouts of a ScrollView are overlapping with each other

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, scrollview, grid-layout, overlapping

I have kivy 1.11.1, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, python 3.8 running on my laptop . I am beginner to kivy and currently working on kivy project, I am stuck on this problem of children gridlayout of scrollview getting overlapped. I have a scroll view with GridLayout and some labels as its children. GridLayout have one Label and a StackLayout which can have different number of entries for different row. Here is source code **main.py**.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from  kivy.effects.scroll import ScrollEffect

kv = '''
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
ScrollApp:

<ScrollApp>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.90
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
        padding: 22, 0, 22, 50
        spacing: 50
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        #   id: streak_zone
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 400   
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .15, .15, .15, .9
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                width: 100
                height: 100
                on_press: print('This button does not overlap the menu above')

            # "ScrollViews containers"
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
    BoxLayout:  
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'bottom':1.0}
        Button:
            on_press: print("This menu at the bottom is not affected by the problem that occurs with the top one")
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        Button:
            text: 'Fixed Menu'
            on_press: print('This button stops working if there is a horizontal scrollview "behind"')


<Custom@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
#   id: streak_zone
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 60
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 20
        text: 'Teste'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 1, 0, .5) # DarkOliveGreen
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    StackLayout:
        id : grid
        size_hint_y: None
        
        ToggleButton:
            text:'1'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'2'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'3'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'4'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'5'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'6'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'7'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'8'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
            

''' 


class ScrollApp(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        kv1 =  Builder.load_string(kv)
        print("jhe ",kv1.height)
        return kv1
        return ScrollApp()

Test().run()
```

I am getting this layout after running it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wERD6.png)

I have read many articles on GridLayout and ScrollView but still unable to fix this issue. What am I missing ?

Updated code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from  kivy.effects.scroll import ScrollEffect

kv = '''
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
ScrollApp:

<ScrollApp>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.90
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
        padding: 22, 0, 22, 50
        spacing: 50
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        #   id: streak_zone
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            #row_force_default: True
            #row_default_height: 400   
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .15, .15, .15, .9
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                width: 100
                height: 100
                on_press: print('This button does not overlap the menu above')

            # "ScrollViews containers"
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
    BoxLayout:  
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'bottom':1.0}
        Button:
            on_press: print("This menu at the bottom is not affected by the problem that occurs with the top one")
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        Button:
            text: 'Fixed Menu'
            on_press: print('This button stops working if there is a horizontal scrollview "behind"')


<Custom@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
#   id: streak_zone
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    #row_force_default: True
    #row_default_height: 60
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 20
        text: 'Teste'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 1, 0, .5) # DarkOliveGreen
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    StackLayout:
        id : grid
        size_hint_y: None
        
        ToggleButton:
            text:'1'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'2'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'3'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'4'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'5'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'6'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'7'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'8'
            size_hint:1/3, 1
            group:'ttt'
            

''' 


class ScrollApp(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        kv1 =  Builder.load_string(kv)
        print("jhe ",kv1.height)
        return kv1
        return ScrollApp()

Test().run()
```

Comment: Python 3.8 is not supported for Kivy. When I run your code on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.9 and kivy 1.11.1, I do not see your problem

Comment: Can you share the output what you getting ?

Comment: The image of my result is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a61a1bx8vtmsdgn/Screenshot%20from%202020-06-21%2014-02-23.png?dl=0).

Comment: I have updated the code previously uploaded code was a bit different  there I set default height and forced it, which is not true always in my case because different stacklayout can have different number of element . You can see in your output also the label text "taste" if getting overlapped with the background of stackLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that whenever you use the `minimum_height` property of `GridLayout`, you must make sure that the size of its children are well defined, and you can't use `size_hint_y` for those children.

So here is a slightly modified version of your `kv` that specifies more `height` properties:

```
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
ScrollApp:

<ScrollApp>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.90
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
        padding: 22, 0, 22, 50
        spacing: 50
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        #   id: streak_zone
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            #row_force_default: True
            #row_default_height: 400   
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .15, .15, .15, .9
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                width: 100
                height: 100
                on_press: print('This button does not overlap the menu above')

            # "ScrollViews containers"
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
            Custom
    BoxLayout:  
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'bottom':1.0}
        Button:
            on_press: print("This menu at the bottom is not affected by the problem that occurs with the top one")
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        Button:
            text: 'Fixed Menu'
            on_press: print('This button stops working if there is a horizontal scrollview "behind"')


<Custom@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
#   id: streak_zone
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    #row_force_default: True
    #row_default_height: 60
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 20
        text: 'Teste'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50

        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0, 1, 0, .5) # DarkOliveGreen
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    StackLayout:
        id : grid
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        ToggleButton:
            text:'1'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'2'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'3'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'4'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'5'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'6'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'7'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
        ToggleButton:
            text:'8'
            size_hint:1/3, None
            height: 50
            group:'ttt'
```